# Is the function of a continuous linear functional to its kernel continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, riesz-representation-theorem

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space, $L\in \mathcal{H}^*$ be a bounded continuous linear functional. Suppose that $\ker\:L \neq \mathcal{H}$.

We know that the dimension of $\ker \:L$ is $1$, i.e. there exists $x(L) \in \mathcal{H}$ with $\|x(L)\| = 1$ such that for all $y \in \ker\: L$, we can write $y = k x$ for some $k\in \mathbb{R}$.

My question is, is the function defined by $f: \mathcal{H}^* \to \mathcal{H}, f(L) \mapsto x(L)$ continuous? That is to say, if two linear functionals are 'close', are their kernels also 'close'? I can't either prove this is correct or give a counter-example.

(PS: this question is the same as asking: In Riesz representation theorem, is the representing element continuous to the linear functional?)

Comment: The Riesz representation theorem gives a surjective linear isometry $H \rightarrow H^*$ (hence a homeomorphism). You may want to double-check your definition of $x(L)$ which makes no sense as is (at least, you can replace $x(L)$ by $-x(L)$ and not change a thing).

Comment: Even if the kernel changes continuously, whatever that means, as soon as you make one choice of one such $x$, you can have a loop that continuously takes $x$ to $-x$ and then you're going to have a continuity problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your function $\ x(L)\ $ is not well-defined, because if $\ \phi(L)=e^{i\psi(L)}\ $, where $\ \psi\ $ is *any* real-valued function on $\ \mathcal{H}^*\ $, then $ \psi(L)x(L)\ $ will satisfy all the the same conditions you've given to specify $\ x(L)\ $.  It's certainly possible to choose $\ \psi\ $ to make $ \psi(L)x(L)\ $ *discontinuous*.

Your question is *not* "the same as asking" whether the representing element in the Riesz representation theorem is a continuous function of the represented functional.  That representative, $ x_L\ $, say, is *unique*, and satisfies the stronger condition, $\ L(y)= \langle x_L, y\rangle\ $ for all $\ y\in \mathcal{H}\ $. As [Mindlack](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/556825/mindlack) has already pointed out, the function $\ L\mapsto x_L\ $ is a linear isometry, and hence continuous.